# Getting color of selected LineString in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, angular, typescript

I have a dynamically generated layers of LineStrokes which get their color from the API call. I only have a basic style for them, to which a color is set when I receive data from API and each layer has its color.

I want to implement a functionality, that when you click on such line, or to be more precise, its section, it will get highlighted.

```typescript
this.selectInstance = new Select({
  condition: (mapBrowserEvent) => click(mapBrowserEvent),
  style: (feature, resolution) => this.setHighlightStyle(feature, resolution),
  hitTolerance: MAP_CONSTANTS.HIT_TOLERANCE,
  filter: (feature) => feature.getProperties()['modelType'] === EntityType.SectionEntity
});

// I was hoping to do something like that, but all I get is style function
// and I'm unable to do anything with it.
private setHighlightStyle(feature: FeatureLike, resolution: number): Style {
  const line = feature as Feature<LineString>;
  const style = line.getStyle();
  // style.clone() doesn't work, style.getColor() neither, I'm stopped by TypeScript
}
```

Any idea how to do it? I'm bit confused from all that Style, StyleLike, Feature, FeatureLike objects and especially functions, like for style.

OpenLayers version: `"ol": "^7.1.0"`

Comment: As you have coded it selecting a feature will set its style to your `setHighlightStyle` function, so calling `getStyle` on a selected feature will always return the `setHighlightStyle` function.  To set around that you would need a `null` style for the Select interaction and update the selected features styles via the interactions `select` event.  To get the line stroke color from a single style object use `style.getStroke().getColor()`.